# how to copy files or folders from svn to frs ? (sourceforge)

Tags: svn, release-management, sourceforge

how to copy jars or folders at svn repository to https://sourceforge.net/projects/project-name/files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check out the files and folders locally from svn and them upload them using any of the methods described on the [SourceForge support page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Release%20files%20for%20download). If you don't know which method to pick use SFTP.

If you don't want to check out the files locally you can use the [SourceForge Shell Service](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Shell%20service) and check out and upload the files using the remote shell.